# Core-Plot crash only in Release Configuration

Tags: iphone, release, core-plot

I really don't know a solution or even an idea to get around the 
following failure. It only happens in Release Configuration on the 
Device - Simulator and Debug Configuration work fine. It also only 
appears on the second launch. So if I have the phone connected to my 
mac, build the application and run it, everything works fine. If I 
then close the app and restart, it crashes. 
After long search, it seems that the error comes from the following 
line:

```
x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromFloat(2.0f);
```

The code before:

```
               CPLayerHostingView *chartView = [[CPLayerHostingView 
alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 160)]; 
                [self addSubview:chartView]; 
                // create an CPXYGraph and host it inside the view 
                CPTheme *theme = [CPTheme themeNamed:kCPPlainWhiteTheme]; 
                CPXYGraph *graph = (CPXYGraph *)[theme newGraph]; 
                chartView.hostedLayer = graph; 
                graph.paddingLeft = 20.0; 
                graph.paddingTop = 10.0; 
                graph.paddingRight = 10.0; 
                graph.paddingBottom = 20.0; 
                CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace; 
                plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange 
plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0) 
                                                                                                           length:CPDecimalFromFloat(100)]; 
                plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange 
plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0) 
                                                                                                           length:CPDecimalFromFloat(10)]; 
                CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet; 
                CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis; 
                x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromFloat(2.0f);
```

If I comment the last line, everything works fine (off course the 
interval length is not correct). 
I would appreciate any help! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does it crash?  Does it throw an exception or crash on an EXC_BAD_ACCESS?  Can you start with breakpoints on and see where it halts within the CPDecimalFromFloat() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance `CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;` is an x that is `nil` or not retained? It is not being checked for.

Comment: hmm, unfortunatly not. I checked it now and it's the right object with right values.